# Get rid of .Select in VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get rid of the `sht2.Select` and `sht2.Range("B2").Select` in the code below. Is there a way to do this?

```
Sub Remaining()

Dim sht2 As Worksheet    
Dim cell As Range

Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

sht2.Select
sht2.Range("B2").Select    
With sht2
    For Each cell In .Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If .Range("A:A").Find(What:=cell.Value2, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
           Intersect(.UsedRange, cell.EntireRow).Offset(, 1).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
           cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
       End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: just delete  these 2 lines, your code will work :) , don't forget to fully qualify your `.Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))` to `.Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))`

Comment: @ShaiRado  Not necessarily - there is an unqualified `Cells()` in the Range() call in the `For Each` line

Comment: Please don't add salutations like "Thanks" to your posts; this isn't a discussion forum :-).

Comment: @TylerH, that seems pretty harsh. I send emails with "Thanks" when I'm only expecting an answer in reply...

Comment: @CallumDA This isn't an e-mail client either. There've been numerous community discussions about not adding thanks (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and other salutations to posts, and it's in the Help Center, too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior Remember that SO is supposed to be a no-nonsense reference of programming problems/questions and answers.

Comment: @CallumDA Thank users by upvoting their posts and accepting their answers to your questions. That's useful signal, as opposed to noise like 'Thanks' or 'Thanks in Advance'.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I take your point on board for future!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub Remaining()

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With sht2
        'A few fixes in the following line to make sure everything
        '   is referencing the correct sheet
        For Each cell In .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            If .Range("A:A").Find(What:=cell.Value2, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
               Intersect(.UsedRange, cell.EntireRow).Offset(, 1).Copy _
                      Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
               cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
           End If
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Comment: Shouldn't you fully qualify your `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1)`  with `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1)` ?

Comment: `sht2` is obtained from the `Worksheets` collection and `"Sheet1"` from the `Sheets` collection. Since "Sheet1" is a `Worksheet` object, it should be obtained from the `Worksheets` collection as well. And ideally, qualified with a workbook, too, indeed @ShaiRado.